# Why won't IE recognize javascript code returned in AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a (hopefully) simple question.

I'm using ajax to update a DIV on my current page.  Within what's being inserted into the div is a script block that defines a variable.  Within FF, I can access the variable, but IE doesn't see the var.  Do I need to eval the returned code in some way for IE to recognize the variable?

As a simple example, if my ajax call returns this snippet of code and gets inserted into the div, I get an alert in FF but not in IE:

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
alert('Foo!');
</script>

Comment: Probably worth specifying which version of IE you're talking about. IE6, 7 and 8 are all quite different beasts. (Nothing is ever a simple question when IE is involved.)

Comment: Hi, sorry the question is somewhat vague.  I'm using IE8, although I've run across the issue in IE7 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the common workaround is to get all the `script` elements using `getElementsByTagName()` and then to `eval()` them.

Comment: Oh how I hate IE ... Can you give me an example? I tried this and still get no alert:

var code = cp.document.getElementById('cpanelBody').getElementsByTagName('script');
for (i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
  eval(code[i]);
}

Comment: May I use jQuery? `$('#somediv').load('ajax.php', null, function() { eval($('#somediv script').text()); } );` Be aware that the code is executed in the context of that inner function.

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look at that, I'm currently using YUI (long story) but could mix in some jQuery just for kicks.  This seems awfully convoluted, though.  All I'm trying to do is introduce a set of data that's going to then get processed further -- maybe I'll just return a form with hidden vars to accomplish what I want instead of passing a JS object directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a JSON object as the result of the AJAX call and then use the json2.js Javascript stuff to evaluate it into a live object.

http://json.org/ has a link to JSON libraries for every language known to man, including Javascript.

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually returning JSON already, in the form {'status':'some status','content':'The content getting stuffed into my page'}.  If status = 'OK', then I put it in the target div and if it's 'Error', I stuff the returned error message into an error div.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be your JavaScript MIME type - you're using an unconventional type (type='text/JavaScript'):

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'> alert('Foo!'); </script>
```

You should try this instead:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Foo!'); </script>
```

I ran some tests recently and found that even modern browsers are pretty picky about this MIME type (skip to Additional Test #1), and will refuse to execute the JavaScript if it isn't set correctly: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/what-happens-when-we-serve-javascript-with-random-mime-types

If that's not the issue, try adding the script to the document Head:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

This is what Google Analytics did until recently, so I would be surprised if it didn't work for you.  You shouldn't need to use eval().

According to this page [this page](https://singpolyma.net/2008/03/jsonp-in-ie/), IE is picky with nodes that haven't yet loaded, but the Head is almost guaranteed to have loaded, which is why it shouldn't have the same issue.